# Why can't sendmail to a Email of Members of a Group from Addins?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I try this code to send mail from my addins:

```
function sendEmail(from, to, cc, bcc, subject, body) {


    var urlTemplate = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': from,
                'To': { 'results': ["ql_kinhdoanh@koivn.onmicrosoft.com"] },               
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
        ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Send mail:success')
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

But it occur error:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2130242040, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.\"}}}","status":400,"statusText":"error"}
```

Email `"ql_kinhdoanh@koivn.onmicrosoft.com"` is valid , I try send by outlook , it is ok.

[image]

User `"ql_kinhdoanh@koivn.onmicrosoft.com"`  is member of Group `[quanly Members]`
and Group `[quanly Members]` is member of site.

Why can't sendmail to a Email of Members of a Group from Addins?

Answer (score 0):

To send email to the users, the user first needs to be add in your site user information list: `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`

Otherwise, you would get the error:  `The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient`

You could use below script to add the user to the user information list；

```
var hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebURL);
var theUser = hostWebContext .get_web().ensureUser("ql_kinhdoanh@koivn.onmicrosoft.com");
context.load(theUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

 alert(theUser.get_title());

},
function(sender, args){

  alert(args.get_message());

});
```